# Appending rows to a .csv file is somehow missing the first two columns of data

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I'm using a function I found here: [Apend2CSV](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/82293-append-csv.html) to append changed rows to a CSV file.  I've used this process successfully in several different projects now, but this time it is leaving out the first two columns that I'm trying to append.  As far as I can tell, everything is set up right, and I'm hoping someone with a better eye for this can point out where my problem is.  The code is triggered by a Worksheet_Change event, but it is a separate procedure because it is also called by other parts of the program.

In this case, Range("A4:BB4") is supposed to get appended, but only Range("C4:BB4") actually does. This is a calculated range with formulas that account for the potential weirdness of .csv, such as quotes and commas in text, by replacing every instance of `"` with `""` and wrapping all values in quotes before the values get appended.

Here's the code:

```
Sub Append2CSV()
    Sheets("ToCSV").Calculate
    Dim tmpCSV As String
    Dim f As Integer
    Const CSVFile As String = "C:\TheCSV\WBCSV.csv"

    f = FreeFile
    Open CSVFile For Append As #f

    tmpCSV = Range2CSV(Sheets("ToCSV").Range("A4:BB4"))

    Print #f, tmpCSV
    Close #f
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Function Range2CSV(list) As String
    Dim tmp As String
    Dim cr As Long
    Dim r As Range

    If TypeName(list) = "Range" Then
        cr = 1
        For Each r In list.Cells
            If r.Row = cr Then
                If tmp = vbNullString Then
                    tmp = r.Value
                Else
                    tmp = tmp & "," & r.Value
                End If
            Else
                cr = cr + 1
                If tmp = vbNullString Then
                    tmp = r.Value
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
    Range2CSV = tmp
End Function
```

Here's the text from the .csv file:

```
A,AscendSKU,UPCNumber,VendorPartNumber,MFGPartNumber,Divison,G,PhysicalQOHAtTimeOfRecord,AscendQOHAtTimeOfRecord,ChosenVendor,Status,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,Cost,Price,V,W,Location,DateRecordCreated,Z,UniqueID,DateTimeSerial,CurrentAscendQOH,CurrentAscendQOO,CurrentAscendYTD,Brand,ClickHereToStartBuyerModeCategory,AH,DateRecordModified,AJ,AK,AL,AM,AN,AO,AP,AQ,AR,AS,AT,AU,AV,AW,AX,AY,ChangedDuringBuyerMode
"","11833300044D","879410002474","ST6284","ST6284","1","1181 HI-RISE 1-1/8""x31.8 STEM","","0","Hawley","","","","","","","","","","9.01","19.99","","","","42277","","42277.5861111111---...---11833300044D","42277.5861111111","","","","ELEVEN81","Parts - Stems - Mountain and Hybrid","","42277.6491435185","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"","CHA27625539K","719676285276","60814-0424","60814-0424","1","16 SPEC CHAMONIX HELMET","","2","Specialized Bicycle Components","","","","","","","","","","19.6","49.99","","","","42277","","42277.5841550926---...---CHA27625539K","42277.5841550926","","","","Specialized","Accessories - Helmets - Road - z.Mens","","42277.6491666666","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"","CHA27625539K","719676285276","60814-0424","60814-0424","1","16 SPEC CHAMONIX HELMET","","2","Specialized Bicycle Components","","","","","","","","","","19.6","49.99","","","","42277","","42277.5841550926---...---CHA27625539K","42277.5841550926","","","","Specialized","Accessories - Helmets - Road - z.Mens","","42277.6491666666","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"","WMS291257455","072774380459","38045","38045","1","WM SOLID RR AXLE SET 3/8x26x126x175","0","0","J & B Importers","","","","","","","","","","1.69","5.99","","","","42041","","42041.6198495370---...---WMS291257455","42041.619849537","","","","WHEEL MASTER","Parts - Hubs - Axles and Nuts and Cones","","42277.6496064815","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"","WMS291257455","072774380459","38045","38045","1","WM SOLID RR AXLE SET 3/8x26x126x175","0","0","J & B Importers","","","","","","","","","","1.69","5.99","","","","42041","","42041.6198495370---...---WMS291257455","42041.619849537","","","","WHEEL MASTER","Parts - Hubs - Axles and Nuts and Cones","","42277.6496064815","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"","FLS17361201Z","036121700116","FL4050","FL4050","1","FL SHOCK OIL 5WT--.--16OZ GET 2","","0","Bicycle Technologies International","O","","","","","","","","","8.95","19.99","","","","42063","","42063.7094444444---...---FLS17361201Z","42063.7094444444","","","","FINISH LINE","Accessories - Maintenance - Suspension Fluid","","42277.6517939815","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"","FLS17361201Z","036121700116","FL4050","FL4050","1","FL SHOCK OIL 5WT--.--16OZ GET 2","","0","Bicycle Technologies International","O","","","","","","","","","8.95","19.99","","","","42063","","42063.7094444444---...---FLS17361201Z","42063.7094444444","","","","FINISH LINE","Accessories - Maintenance - Suspension Fluid","","42277.6552893519","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"","FLS17361201Z","036121700116","FL4050","FL4050","1","FL SHOCK OIL 5WT--.--16OZ GET 2","","0","Bicycle Technologies International","O","","","","","","","","","8.95","19.99","","","","42063","","42063.7094444444---...---FLS17361201Z","42063.7094444444","","","","FINISH LINE","Accessories - Maintenance - Suspension Fluid","","42277.6552893519","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"","SPE298655664","719676126357","542-3700","542-3700","1","SPEC FLATBOY GLUELESS PATCHKIT '14""","8","18","Specialized Bicycle Components","","","","","","","","","","1.44","2.99","","","","42063","","42063.7109722222---...---SPE298655664","42063.7109722222","","","","Specialized","Accessories - Flat Repair and Prevention - Patch Kits - Glueless","","42277.6569791666","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
```

Comment: Could you add a sample of the CSV file, as well, please?  A few rows would probably be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not seeing a way to do that.  How do I add a file?

Comment: You can edit your post (click edit) and paste the first 3-5 lines of the file-- or paste a mockup of the data if it's sensitive.  It's so we can see how it's formatted

Comment: Oh boy, that's ugly...  It is a lot of columns.

Comment: Do the first two columns of the data being exported have any content?

Comment: The first is always blank and the 2nd usually does have content but can be blank as well.  In all of my testing, the 2nd column has always had data but still gets excluded.  And actually, what's being appended for blank cells isn't blank; it's two double quotes like this: ""

Comment: Thanks for the edit Tim Williams; I didn't realize I could post that as code.  Much better!

Comment: I'm confused by the use of `r.Row` in `Range2CSV` - in your example `r.Row` will always be 4...

Comment: It is in this example, but I use the exact same code with a variable range elsewhere successfully.  In those, the range can be (and often is) 1 row, but can also be thousands of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll throw in my 2c

Sub for testing:

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim s, fso
    s = getCsvContent(Range("A1").CurrentRegion)
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    With fso.createtextfile("C:\users\yournamehere\desktop\temp.csv", True)
        .write s
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

Function to convert a range to CSV:

```
Function getCsvContent(rng As Range)
    Dim data, r As Long, c As Long, sep, lb, s, tmp
    data = rng.Value
    s = ""
    lb = ""
    For r = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
        s = s & lb
        sep = ""
        For c = 1 To UBound(data, 2)
            tmp = data(r, c)
            If IsError(tmp) Then tmp = "#Error!" '<<handle errors
            If InStr(tmp, """") > 0 Then
                tmp = Replace(tmp, """", """""")
            End If
            If InStr(tmp, ",") > 0 Then
                tmp = """" & tmp & """"
            End If
            s = s & sep & tmp
            sep = ","
        Next c
        lb = vbNewLine
    Next r
    getCsvContent = s
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Tim.  This does actually grab the first 2 columns that were previously missing (at least in your Tester()), but the "" that are produced by my formulas to indicate blank values, along with the indication of an actual " within a text field, are messed up by this.  The problem is that many of the fields being appended can contain commas and double quotes.

Comment: It does work if I remove the 2 If InStr() statements from the middle though.  I'll test it out with the actual append here in a bit.

Comment: Yep, that did the trick.  I do have to stick with my formulas though.  I need to be able to append a string that looks like this: STEM,1181,HI-RISE 1-1/8"-BLK   where the commas and the " are part of the appended text.  My formulas turn double quotes into 2 double quotes, and wrap all fields in double quotes so that this same string would look like this when it's ready to append:  "STEM,1181,HI-RISE 1-1/8""-BLK".

Comment: If I save the output from my function to a file and then open that with Excel, it reproduces the source content correctly (inluding the sample value you provided). Comma-containing values in a CSV file need to be quoted, and values which contain a quote need to have the quote(s) doubled-up.  **Don't use the input from your "CSV-fixing" formulas for my function: it will handle the values correctly without doing that.**

Comment: I did try it without my formulas, and I originally thought it turns single instances of double quotes in the returned text into 2 double quotes, so 1/8" becomes 1/8"", but it turns out that my actual value had 2 double quotes!  Your solutions works perfectly.  So does mine now though, and it seems a little less complicated.  I wonder which one is more efficient?

Comment: "Efficient" is difficult to quantify, but I generally would prefer to handle distinct tasks like this in a single re-usable piece of code which doesn't rely on intermediate steps.  Trouble-shooting is much easier when there's just one place you need to look.

Comment: Actually, my solution is far less efficient than yours, and that is pretty important because this function will also be transferring thousands of rows to a csv file several times a session as well.  I just timed them, and yours took 5.69 seconds to process 4000 rows, and mine took 239.71 seconds for the same 4000 rows...  Yours is waaay better!

Comment: If performance is important to you then you should consider using a "StringBuilder" class to build up the CSV content.  For example see http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/67596/a-lightning-fast-stringbuilder   Building strings of any length in VBA just using `&` to concatenate is horribly inefficient: every time you add new text the whole string is re-allocated in memory, and doing that thousands of times for a large strings is very slow.

Answer (score 0):

This works with multiple rows as well:

```
Private Function Range2CSV(list) As String
    Dim tmp As String
    Dim cr As Long
    Dim r As Range

    If TypeName(list) = "Range" Then
       cr = list.Row
       For Each r In list.Cells
        If r.Row = cr Then
           tmp = IIf(tmp = vbNullString, r.Value2, tmp & "," & r.Value2)
        Else
           tmp = IIf(r.Rows.Count Mod r.Row, tmp & vbCrLf & r.Value2, tmp & "," & r.Value2)
           cr = r.Row
        End If
      Next
    End If
    Range2CSV = tmp
End Function
```

---

Tested it with row A4:BB4 containing the series 1,2,3,... to 54

Result:

```
A,AscendSKU,UPCNumber,VendorPartNumber,MFGPartNumber,Divison,G,PhysicalQOHAtTimeOfRecord,AscendQOHAtTimeOfRecord,ChosenVendor,Status,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,Cost,Price,V,W,Location,DateRecordCreated,Z,UniqueID,DateTimeSerial,CurrentAscendQOH,CurrentAscendQOO,CurrentAscendYTD,Brand,ClickHereToStartBuyerModeCategory,AH,DateRecordModified,AJ,AK,AL,AM,AN,AO,AP,AQ,AR,AS,AT,AU,AV,AW,AX,AY,ChangedDuringBuyerMode
"","11833300044D","879410002474","ST6284","ST6284","1","1181 HI-RISE 1-1/8""x31.8 STEM","","0","Hawley","","","","","","","","","","9.01","19.99","","","","42277","","42277.5861111111---...---11833300044D","42277.5861111111","","","","ELEVEN81","Parts - Stems - Mountain and Hybrid","","42277.6491435185","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"","CHA27625539K","719676285276","60814-0424","60814-0424","1","16 SPEC CHAMONIX HELMET","","2","Specialized Bicycle Components","","","","","","","","","","19.6","49.99","","","","42277","","42277.5841550926---...---CHA27625539K","42277.5841550926","","","","Specialized","Accessories - Helmets - Road - z.Mens","","42277.6491666666","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"","CHA27625539K","719676285276","60814-0424","60814-0424","1","16 SPEC CHAMONIX HELMET","","2","Specialized Bicycle Components","","","","","","","","","","19.6","49.99","","","","42277","","42277.5841550926---...---CHA27625539K","42277.5841550926","","","","Specialized","Accessories - Helmets - Road - z.Mens","","42277.6491666666","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"","WMS291257455","072774380459","38045","38045","1","WM SOLID RR AXLE SET 3/8x26x126x175","0","0","J & B Importers","","","","","","","","","","1.69","5.99","","","","42041","","42041.6198495370---...---WMS291257455","42041.619849537","","","","WHEEL MASTER","Parts - Hubs - Axles and Nuts and Cones","","42277.6496064815","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"","WMS291257455","072774380459","38045","38045","1","WM SOLID RR AXLE SET 3/8x26x126x175","0","0","J & B Importers","","","","","","","","","","1.69","5.99","","","","42041","","42041.6198495370---...---WMS291257455","42041.619849537","","","","WHEEL MASTER","Parts - Hubs - Axles and Nuts and Cones","","42277.6496064815","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"","FLS17361201Z","036121700116","FL4050","FL4050","1","FL SHOCK OIL 5WT--.--16OZ GET 2","","0","Bicycle Technologies International","O","","","","","","","","","8.95","19.99","","","","42063","","42063.7094444444---...---FLS17361201Z","42063.7094444444","","","","FINISH LINE","Accessories - Maintenance - Suspension Fluid","","42277.6517939815","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"","FLS17361201Z","036121700116","FL4050","FL4050","1","FL SHOCK OIL 5WT--.--16OZ GET 2","","0","Bicycle Technologies International","O","","","","","","","","","8.95","19.99","","","","42063","","42063.7094444444---...---FLS17361201Z","42063.7094444444","","","","FINISH LINE","Accessories - Maintenance - Suspension Fluid","","42277.6552893519","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"","FLS17361201Z","036121700116","FL4050","FL4050","1","FL SHOCK OIL 5WT--.--16OZ GET 2","","0","Bicycle Technologies International","O","","","","","","","","","8.95","19.99","","","","42063","","42063.7094444444---...---FLS17361201Z","42063.7094444444","","","","FINISH LINE","Accessories - Maintenance - Suspension Fluid","","42277.6552893519","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"","SPE298655664","719676126357","542-3700","542-3700","1","SPEC FLATBOY GLUELESS PATCHKIT '14""","8","18","Specialized Bicycle Components","","","","","","","","","","1.44","2.99","","","","42063","","42063.7109722222---...---SPE298655664","42063.7109722222","","","","Specialized","Accessories - Flat Repair and Prevention - Patch Kits - Glueless","","42277.6569791666","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
A4:BB4
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54
A5:BB5
54,53,52,51,50,49,48,47,46,45,44,43,42,41,40,39,38,37,36,35,34,33,32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1
54,53,52,51,50,49,48,47,46,45,44,43,42,41,40,39,38,37,36,35,34,33,32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1
54,53,52,51,50,49,48,47,46,45,44,43,42,41,40,39,38,37,36,35,34,33,32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1
A4:BB5
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54
54,53,52,51,50,49,48,47,46,45,44,43,42,41,40,39,38,37,36,35,34,33,32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54
54,53,52,51,50,49,48,47,46,45,44,43,42,41,40,39,38,37,36,35,34,33,32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54
54,53,52,51,50,49,48,47,46,45,44,43,42,41,40,39,38,37,36,35,34,33,32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1
```

Comment: Nothing changed.  It's still leaving off the first 2 columns.

Comment: I made and update after replicating the issue and testing it, please confirm

Comment: It's still leaving off the 2 columns.  I'v figured out a workaround now, but I'd sure like to know what in the world is going on with this...  My workaround is to move the data to append over 2 columns, and append the original range including the 2 columns to the right.  That gets the data I need appended, but this is just boggling my mind!  Thanks for all your help.  I've got to go for the time being, but I'll be back staring at this stuff tomorrow.

Comment: Made another update but this one was just testing and checking that it accepts more than 1 row of data - I included the test results in the answer (not sure what else can be wrong other than whatever data you have on the sheet; maybe that's causing some issues)

Comment: This does work as long as the first column is actually not null, which in my case is always going to be true, but wouldn't always be the case for all potential uses.

Comment: Or should I say, first cell is actually not null.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that the Range2CSV function is designed to do, but this will work if you just want to get a range as a CSV string:

```
Private Function Range2CSV(ByVal list As Range) As String
    Dim tmp As String
    Dim r As Range
    Dim rowNum As Long

    rowNum = list.Cells(1, 1).Row
    For Each r In list.Cells
        If r.Row <> rowNum Then
            rowNum = r.Row
            tmp = Left(tmp, Len(tmp) - 1) & vbCrLf  'remove last comma and start new line
        End If
        tmp = tmp & r.Value & ","
    Next
    tmp = Left(tmp, Len(tmp) - 1) & vbCrLf  'remove final comma

    Range2CSV = tmp
End Function
```

Comment: Nice and short. This only works with one row but should be fine, except for the extra "," at the start of the line (you may want to just remove it at the end: `Range2CSV = Right(tmp, Len(tmp) - 1)`

Comment: This works and adds the extra lines, but it also adds an extra blank row with each append...  I thought maybe it was the &vbCrLf at the end, but removing that causes the new row to append to the end of the existing row instead of on a new line.

Comment: What if you replace vbCrLf with vbNewLine?

Comment: It still does the same thing.  I just tried it both ways.  The answer I provided earlier this morning works perfectly in all conditions I can think of, so I'm satisfied, albeit maybe still a little confused about how this could work in one project and not in another.  I think maybe I just lucked out and my other projects using this function have never had a blank first cell before...

Answer (score 0):

To deal with the problem of blank first cell, you can add the indicated line below to your code (tested). Eventually, this answer does not address other issues if any.

```
Private Function Range2CSV(list) As String
    Dim tmp As String
    Dim cr As Long
    Dim r As Range

    If TypeName(list) = "Range" Then
        cr = 1
        For Each r In list.Cells
            If r.Row = cr Then
                If tmp = vbNullString Then
                     tmp = r.Value
                     If tmp = vbNullString Then tmp = ","  ' <~~~~ add this line
                Else
                    tmp = tmp & "," & r.Value
                End If
            Else
                cr = cr + 1
                tmp = r.Value
            End If
        Next
    End If
    Range2CSV = tmp
End Function
```

Comment: I misspoke when I mentioned blank cells earlier.  None of them are actually blank, just the values that can be retrieved into excel from the csv using " as a text identifier are.  In the append process, all "blank" values are represented by a "".  So, I can append an entire row of blank values that looks like this: "","","","","","","","","","".  It doesn't matter how many blank values there are; it is still missing the first 2 columns somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, but this only output the last row of data within the `list`.

```
Private Function Range2CSV(list) As String
    Dim sLine As String, sVal As String
    Dim cr As Long
    Dim r As Range

    If TypeName(list) = "Range" Then
        cr = 0 ' Current Row
        For Each r In list.Cells
            ' Check row changes
            If r.Row <> cr Then
                sLine = ""
                cr = r.Row
            End If
            If r.Row = cr Then
                ' Store cell value
                If IsEmpty(r) Then
                    sVal = """""" ' "" in the string output
                Else
                    sVal = r.Value
                End If
                ' Set or Join the values together
                If Len(sLine) = 0 Then
                    sLine = sVal
                Else
                    sLine = sLine & "," & sVal
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If

    Range2CSV = sLine
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided that I wanted to go ahead and try to account for the possibility of an actually blank (null) first cell within a range being appended to a .csv file without wrapping text in quotes, etc. The following is what I came up with.  It works regardless of the value or lack thereof in the first cell, or anywhere else within the range being appended.

As it turns out, this method is actually super inefficient when processing thousands of rows (takes several minutes to complete.)  The solution offered by Tim Williams is much faster, taking less than 6 seconds to complete.

```
Private Function Range2CSV(list) As String
Dim tmp As String
Dim cr As Long
Dim r As Range
Dim St As Integer

St = 1
tmp = vbNullString
If TypeName(list) = "Range" Then
    cr = list.Row
    For Each r In list.Cells
        If r.Row = cr Then
            tmp = IIf(St = 1, """" & Replace(r.Value, """", """""") & """", tmp & "," & """" & Replace(r.Value, """", """""") & """")
        Else
            tmp = IIf(r.Rows.Count Mod r.Row, tmp & vbCrLf & """" & Replace(r.Value, """", """""") & """", tmp & "," & """" & Replace(r.Value, """", """""") & """")
            cr = r.Row
        End If
        St = 2
    Next
End If
Range2CSV = tmp
End Function
```

Thanks to everyone for their input.  Paul Bica, your answer got me the closest, but it was having problems with the concept in this line:  tmp = IIf(tmp = vbNullString, r.Value2, tmp & "," & r.Value2)
By defining St and checking whether the loop was looking at the first cell in the range, I was able to account for that cell having or not having a value to treat the tmp appropriately.